# How do I get a local path and alter it in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a local path like this `C:\test\1\2\3\x\z\6\7\8` How do I insert a `y` folder in this hierarchy between `x` and `z` folders using PowerShell, assuming the folder names are random but the hierarchy is always the same

Tried `Get-ChildItem` `Split-Path` `Split-Path` `Join-Path` functions but didn't get the expected results...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

**To match by *position in the hierarchy*:**

```
'C:\test\1\2\3\x\z\6\7\8' -replace '(?<=^([^\\]+\\){6})', 'y\'
```

Note:

- For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex 101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/kwaEKj/3); in essence, the *position* after the `6` `\`-separated components from the start of the path is matched (via a positive *look-behind assertion*, `(?<=...)`), and the name of the new folder, followed by `\`, is inserted (that is, the *position* of the match is "replaced", resulting in effective *insertion*).
- Should the real folder name (represented by `y` here) happen to contain `$` chars., escape them as `$$`; see below and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for more information.

**To match by folder *names*, anywhere *inside* the hierarchy:**

```
'C:\test\1\2\3\x\z\6\7\8' -replace '\\(x)\\(z)\\', '\$1\y\$2\'
```

Note:

- Because `\` is a *metacharacter* in regexes, it must be escaped as `\\`

  - If your concrete folder names (represented by `x` and `z` here) happen to contain regex metacharacters too (say `.`), they too must be `\`-escaped; alternatively, escape the names as a whole with [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape).
- `(...)`, i.e. *capture groups* are used to capture the surrounding folder names, so they can be referred to via placeholders `$1` and `$2` in the substitution expression (which itself is *not* a regular expression; only `$` chars. are metacharacters there; literal use requires `$$`).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do using a [`DirectoryInfo` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-7.0), a [`do` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.3) to traverse it's hierarchy, [`Path.Combine` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0) and a [`Stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=net-6.0):

```
$insertAfter    = 'x'
$folderToInsert = 'y'
$directory = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] 'C:\test\1\2\3\x\z\6\7\8'
$segments  = [System.Collections.Stack]::new()

do {
    if($directory.BaseName -eq $insertAfter) {
        $segments.Push($folderToInsert)
    }
    $segments.Push($directory.BaseName)
    $directory = $directory.Parent
} while($directory)

[IO.Path]::Combine.Invoke([string[]] $segments)
```

Assuming `C:\test\1\2\3\x\z\6\7\8` was a real directory, then you can use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7.3) instead:

```
$directory = Get-Item 'C:\test\1\2\3\x\z\6\7\8'
```